Unity animator stuck in empty (default state) while console logs tells me the other animations are triggered
I have been trying to get this to work, I need for my animator to handle 4 animations at the moment Pickup, Drop, ShowClipboard and HideClipboard. I'm only having issues with the last two. I want to toggle with tab button the ShowClipboard and HideClipboard animation .When I play and simultaneously look at the animator and press tab I see that the animation is stuck on the empty state. In my logs I see that the triggers for these are being called but the animations just don't play. Can someone please explain this to me or what are the best practices in Unity when it comes to multiple animations? is my problem code related or bad animator setup?or both? I'll post some screenshots and my code to get feedback!

Here is my code is a bit long but I think well structured:
Intended outcome:I want is that the player is able to toggle with the tab key between the ShowClipboard and HideClipboard animation, this should happen after the player picks up a clipboard and it gets added to a clipboardSlot UI.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PickableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text tabHintText; // Reference to the Text component of TabHint
    private Image clipboardSlotImage; // Reference to the Image component of ClipboardSlot
    private static bool isAnyObjectPickedUp = false;
    private bool isClipboardPickedUp = false;
    private bool isClipboardVisible = false;
    private bool isPlayerInRange = false;
    private Transform playerHand;
    private bool isPickedUp = false;
    private bool isFirstAnimationActive = true;
    private Vector3 originalScale;

    public Vector3 positionOffset;
    public Vector3 rotationOffset;

    public GameObject interactionPromptE;
    public GameObject interactionPromptQ;
    public GameObject arms;
    public GameObject clipboard;

    private Animator clipboardAnimator;
    private MouseLook mouseLook;

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize variables
        InitializeUIComponents();
        FindPlayerHand();
        InitializeClipboardAnimator();
        HideInteractionPrompts();
        HideArmsAtStart();
    }

    private void InitializeUIComponents()
    {
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");

        // Find and assign the clipboardSlotImage and tabHintText components
        clipboardSlotImage = canvas.transform.Find("ClipboardSlot")?.GetComponent<Image>();
        tabHintText = canvas.transform.Find("TabHint")?.GetComponent<Text>();

        if (clipboardSlotImage == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("ClipboardSlot Image component not found!");
        }
        if (tabHintText == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("TabHint Text component not found!");
        }

        // Initially hide the UI elements
        clipboardSlotImage?.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        tabHintText?.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void FindPlayerHand()
    {
        playerHand = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform.Find("HandPosition");
        if (playerHand == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("HandPosition not found! Check hierarchy and path.");
        }
        originalScale = transform.localScale;
    }

    private void InitializeClipboardAnimator()
    {
        clipboardAnimator = clipboard.GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (clipboardAnimator != null)
        {
            clipboardAnimator.ResetTrigger("Show");
            clipboardAnimator.ResetTrigger("Hide");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Animator component found on the clipboard!");
        }
    }

    private void HideInteractionPrompts()
    {
        interactionPromptE?.SetActive(false);
        interactionPromptQ?.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void HideArmsAtStart()
    {
        if (arms != null)
        {
            Animator animator = arms.GetComponent<Animator>();
            if (animator != null)
            {
                animator.ResetTrigger("PickUp");
                animator.ResetTrigger("Drop");
            }
            arms.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Arms object not found at the start!");
        }

        mouseLook = Camera.main.GetComponent<MouseLook>();
        if (mouseLook == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("MouseLook script not found on the Main Camera!");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !isPickedUp && !isAnyObjectPickedUp)
        {
            isPlayerInRange = true;
            interactionPromptE?.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            isPlayerInRange = false;
            interactionPromptE?.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isPlayerInRange && !isPickedUp && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            PickUpObject();
        }
        else if (isPickedUp && !isClipboardPickedUp && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            DropObject();
        }

        if (clipboardSlotImage != null && clipboardSlotImage.gameObject.activeSelf && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            ToggleClipboardAnimations();
        }
    }

    void PickUpObject()
    {
        isPickedUp = true;

        if (gameObject.CompareTag("Clipboard"))
        {
            isClipboardPickedUp = true;
            isClipboardVisible = true;
            clipboardSlotImage?.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            tabHintText?.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            StartCoroutine(DisableClipboardWithDelay());
        }
        else
        {
            isAnyObjectPickedUp = true;
            interactionPromptQ?.SetActive(true);
        }

        EnableArms();

        if (arms != null)
        {
            Animator animator = arms.GetComponent<Animator>();
            if (animator != null)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("PickUp");

                if (isClipboardPickedUp)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(HideArmsAfterAnimation(animator));
                }
            }

            if (mouseLook != null)
            {
                mouseLook.areArmsActive = true;
            }
        }

        AttachObjectToHand();
    }

    void AttachObjectToHand()
    {
        transform.SetParent(playerHand);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.localPosition = positionOffset;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationOffset);

        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            rb.useGravity = false;
        }

        interactionPromptE?.SetActive(false);
    }

    void DropObject()
    {
        isPickedUp = false;
        isAnyObjectPickedUp = false;
        Animator animator = arms.GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (animator != null)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Drop");
            StartCoroutine(DisableArmsAfterAnimation(animator));
        }
        DetachObjectFromHand();

        interactionPromptQ?.SetActive(false);
    }

    void DetachObjectFromHand()
    {
        transform.SetParent(null);
        transform.localScale = originalScale;

        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.useGravity = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisableClipboardWithDelay()
    {
        yield return null; // You can use `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` if necessary
        clipboard.SetActive(false);
        DisableArms();
        if (mouseLook != null)
        {
            mouseLook.areArmsActive = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HideArmsAfterAnimation(Animator animator)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);

        if (!isClipboardPickedUp || !isClipboardVisible)
        {
            DisableArms();
            if (mouseLook != null)
            {
                mouseLook.areArmsActive = false;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisableArmsAfterAnimation(Animator animator)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);
        DisableArms();
        if (mouseLook != null)
        {
            mouseLook.areArmsActive = false;
        }
    }

    void ToggleClipboardAnimations()
    {
        EnableArms();
        if (mouseLook != null)
        {
            mouseLook.areArmsActive = false;
        }

        if (isFirstAnimationActive)
        {
            ShowClipboard();
            Debug.Log("Show Clipboard Triggered");
        }
        else
        {
            HideClipboard();
            Debug.Log("Hide Clipboard Triggered");
        }

        isFirstAnimationActive = !isFirstAnimationActive;
    }

    void ShowClipboard()
    {
        if (!clipboardAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("ShowClipboard"))
        {
            clipboardAnimator?.SetTrigger("Show");
            Debug.Log("ShowClipboard state triggered");
        }
    }

    void HideClipboard()
    {
        if (!clipboardAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("HideClipboard"))
        {
            clipboardAnimator?.SetTrigger("Hide");
            Debug.Log("HideClipboard state triggered");
        }
    }

    void EnableArms()
    {
        if (arms != null)
        {
            arms.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void DisableArms()
    {
        if (arms != null)
        {
            arms.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

I tried bool instead of triggers, I didn't get them to work
I tried using a whole other animator
I tried connecting the HideClipboard to anystate directly and didn't work
I dont know what else to try :(

can you attach a screen print of your animation variables, and for example the condition line to move between default and one of the animation points

Just in general: if you anyway check for the state names .. then you don't have to rely on triggers and transitions ... You could just directly use CrossFade

I recommend a bool whenever you can use one, instead of a trigger. It's more reliable and you don't need to reset it anytime it fires. There's a very nice talk from a few years ago by the ppl who made Firewatch (either GDC or Unite) and they explained a few things about managing complexity.
